# elasticsearch JVM memory red

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm, logstash

I have a 3-node elasticsearch cluster.

My ES heap size is configured to 1Gb on each node.

Max locked memory is set to unlimited. Mem alloc is set to true on all nodes.

ulimit -v shows unlimited.

My nodes are up on KVM VMs.

I started logstash / elasticsearch and I once I get a substancial amount of logs, elasticsearch JVM Memory % turns red close to 100% and jvm never releases memory.

Does anyone know how to effectively tune jvm so the GC works effectively and the memory doesn't get saturated because my nodes end up crashing.

Thank you

Comment: The memory used by ES is correspond to your logs size. Please add more memory to your cluster.

Comment: If you could add more info about number of indexes, shards, number of documents, total system memory etc that would be helpful. Adding the output from cluster stats would be even more helpful http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-stats.html

Comment: Nodes: 3 Indices: 24 Shards: 84 Data: 93.04 GB Documents: 60 millions 3 shards / index, 1 replication. So far, es heap up to 10gb per node. Node physical memory 16gb.   Expecting 25 billions documents / year. What would be the minimum ideal environment memorywise?